# Best citations database

Tags: citations

Which online service provides the most complete list of citations to given mathematical paper? I mean the citations both in published papers and in preprints. I guess scholar.google is the best, maybe there is something more powerfull?

Comment: Could you say what you would like to do with the citation information? In my experience Google Scholar gives a lot (most?) but also some 'false positives' (whether this is a problem depends on context). Eg, I once wrote an informal summary of my research activity and put this on my personal webpage. Now GS considers this as a 'paper' and 'counts' the references from there. I goess similar things could happpen for informal lecture notes, transripts from talks and so on. So GS is over-complete (which might or might not be a problem). MathSciNet has sort of the opposite 'problem'.      .  

Comment: I do not give this as an answer as I never used it:
Thomson Reuters, creating eg Journal Impact Factors, also provide more individual citation statistics, which I assume to be quite sizeable. See http://wokinfo.com/ and in the dropdown you can find among many other things 'citations'.(Needs subscription, I guess.)

Comment: The classical one is Science Citation Index.  In the old days before the Internet, every research library would have it, and using it was a skill you had to develop.  They are now on-line, if your institution subscribes.  But there are (as noted here) many alternatives.

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: I strongly believe this is (part of) what I linked to. 
The ISI (Institute for Scientific Information) creating among others the SCI you mention was bought some time ago by Thomson (Reuters).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience google gives you much more than others, but it is not "clean"

There are also

Those who have subscription (me not) use MathSciNet 
http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/

Or european analogue
http://www.zentralblatt-math.org/zmath/

Also there is Russian 
http://www.mathnet.ru/
But it is not so developed. But it is free.

Free:
http://academic.research.microsoft.com/

Free:
http://www.citebase.org/

Publishing houses like Springer Elseveir provide citation services, but it is mainly within their own journals...

Comment: MathSciNet does not include preprint information, but it does get the citations on-line long before the actual review.

Comment: To me the main issue with MathSciNet citation information is that contrary to what one could assume it does not take into account the citations from all journals it indexes but just of some selected group (and this only since somewhat recently). Of course also other services like SCI do not index everything but what to me is slightly worrying is that perhaps some people *think* all (sufficiently recent) articles in MathSciNet contribute to the citation count and then get mislead.  

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the ones Alexander Chervov has mentioned, there are:

1. [The SAO/NASA Astrophysics Data System](http://www.adsabs.harvard.edu/)
2. (Deprecated as of 2018 - old site now hosts porn) Eprintweb

Answer (score 1):

Thought this might be interesting.

I became curious and googled for "mathematics citation database".

Could not find anything not mentioned here already, except for the following.

At http://mathematics.library.cornell.edu/find/Mathematics-Databases they have

[Jahrbuch-Project Electronic Research Archive for Mathematics](http://www.emis.de/MATH/JFM/JFM.html). A resource for searching mathematics literature from from 1868 to 1943.

Going there, it is based (I believe) on the Zentralblatt interface, but seems to be particularly sharpened towards old research. They say in particular

> 17 772 links to facsimiles

Might be useful I think.